# Filter multi-dimensional array (recursively) inwards to outwards using custom functions

Tags: php

**Note**

This question is NOT a duplicate of

- [Filtering multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46975290/3679900)
- [Filter out empty array elements of multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46540597/3679900)

or [several other related questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20filter%20multidimensional%20array%20by%20custom%20function%20site:stackoverflow.com&safe=active)

---

I have a very peculiar use case where I have to filter a multi-dimensional array 'inwards to outwards', implying

> "filter the innermost level elements, then it's preceding level
> elements and so on until coming to filtering the topmost level"

---

As an (dummy, mock) example, consider this

suppose we have a nested of restaurant-ids (res_ids) grouped by countries (1, 2, & 3) & cities (11, 12, 21, 22, 23, 31)

```
[
     1 => [
         11 => [
             111 => ['res_id' => 111, 'city_id' => 11, 'country_id' => 1],
             112 => ['res_id' => 112, 'city_id' => 11, 'country_id' => 1],
             113 => ['res_id' => 113, 'city_id' => 11, 'country_id' => 1],
         ],
         12 => [
             121 => ['res_id' => 121, 'city_id' => 12, 'country_id' => 1],
         ],
     ],
     2 => [
         21 => [
             212 => ['res_id' => 212, 'city_id' => 21, 'country_id' => 2],
             214 => ['res_id' => 214, 'city_id' => 21, 'country_id' => 2],
         ],
         22 => [
             221 => ['res_id' => 221, 'city_id' => 22, 'country_id' => 2],
             222 => ['res_id' => 222, 'city_id' => 22, 'country_id' => 2],
             223 => ['res_id' => 223, 'city_id' => 22, 'country_id' => 2],
         ],
     ],
     3 => [
         31 => [
             312 => ['res_id' => 312, 'city_id' => 21, 'country_id' => 2],
             314 => ['res_id' => 314, 'city_id' => 21, 'country_id' => 2],
         ],
     ]
]
```

- and we want to remove all restaurants (plus the parent sub-array structure) having even res_ids (keep odd ones)
- so that resulting output nested array is as follows

  - *note that not only individual 'leaf' items depicting res have been filtered, but also higher level city and country items have been filtered if they contained only even res_ids (which we intended to remove)*

```
[
     1 => [
         11 => [
             111 => ['res_id' => 111, 'city_id' => 11, 'country_id' => 1],
             113 => ['res_id' => 113, 'city_id' => 11, 'country_id' => 1],
         ],
         12 => [
             121 => ['res_id' => 121, 'city_id' => 12, 'country_id' => 1],
         ],
     ],
     2 => [
         22 => [
             221 => ['res_id' => 221, 'city_id' => 22, 'country_id' => 2],
             223 => ['res_id' => 223, 'city_id' => 22, 'country_id' => 2],
         ],
     ],
]
```

*actually i myself created above array from a flat array by [recursive grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64812229/3679900); but now I have to filter them in groups (which can't be done before grouping)*

---

- While i can certainly do this using nested loops, I was wondering if we can create a generic function for it (i have other such multi-dimensional filtering use-cases *at different depths* across my project)
- Another important thing to note here that given the *generic* filtering criteria requirement, we would ideally like to be able to have a different filtering criteria per level: custom functions per se.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this lika a array_filter callback.

`$currentKey` is not required, but may be handy.

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/ulN1W).

```
function array_filter_clean(array $array, array $callbacks, $currentDepth = 0, $currentKey = '') {
    if (array_key_exists($currentDepth, $callbacks)) { // identify node to apply callback to
        $callback = $callbacks[$currentDepth];
        if (!$callback($currentKey, $array)) { // empty node when callback returns false (or falsy)
            return [];
        }
    }
    
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) { // &value to modify $array
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_filter_clean($value, $callbacks, $currentDepth+1, $key); // recurse if array
        }
    }
    
    return array_filter($array); // remove empty nodes (you may want to add "afterCallbacks" here)
}

$callbacksByDepth = [
    /* 2 => function ($key, $value) {
        return $key > 20;
    }, */ // test
    3 => function ($key, $value) {
        return $value['res_id']%2;
    },
];

$output = array_filter_clean($input, $callbacksByDepth);

print_r($output);
```

I've added comments - in case i forgot to explain something please let me know.

#### Worth mentioning

This can be done with an extension of [`RecursiveFilterIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivefilteriterator.php) within a `RecursiveIteratorIterator` - but the readability of the provided solution is far superior.

#### Note

Given the case you want to keep every node which contains at least 3 items after you've applied your callback, you will have to extend this funtion (at the last line). You could do exactly the same like above `array_key_exists($currentDepth, $callbacksXXX)` for another `$callbacksAfter` array with the same structure. (Or build everything in one array and key your callbacks with `before` and `after` - up to you)

Answer (score 0):

- I came up with following function that accepts a *list of `callables`*, each one of which is used for filtering the array at a single level

  - in-line with the original example, filtering is done 'inwards to outwards': first we filter the innermost level, then the one above that and so on (so essentially the nth filter acts on residual output obtained by applying n-1 filters before it)
  - have a look at the [unit-tests](https://gist.github.com/y2k-shubham/52f6f8e0e4ae566607ee6aec658a441c#file-arrayutilstest-php-L1797) to understand the behaviour

```
/**
 * Filters a multi-dimensional array recursively by applying series of filtering function callables, each at a
 * different level. Filtering is done starting from innermost depth and moving outwards.
 * It is assumed that structure / depth of array is consistent throughout (each key grows upto same max depth)
 *
 * Regarding $filter_callables
 *  - this is a series of filtering functions (callables) applied at each level (1st callable is for first /
 *    top-most or outer-most level, next callable is for next level at depth 2 and so on)
 *  - each filter callable function should accept exactly 2 arguments: (1) the value or item and (2) the key of item
 *    as mandated by 'ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH' flag of PHP's array_filter function
 *  - to skip applying filtering at a level, we can pass null (instead of callable) for that position
 *  - no of callables should be less than or equal to depth of array (or else exception will be thrown)
 *
 * see test-cases to understand further (plus detailed explaination)
 * @param array $nested_array Nested array to be filtered resursively
 * @param array $filter_callables List of callables to be used as 'filter' functions at each 'depth' level
 * @return array Recursively filtered array
 */
public static function filterByFnRecursive(array $nested_array, array $filter_callables): array {
    if (empty($nested_array) || empty($filter_callables)) {
        // base case: if array is empty (empty array was passed) or no more callables left to be applied, return
        return $nested_array;
    } else {
        // retrieve first callable (meant for this level)
        $filterer = array_shift($filter_callables);

        if (!empty($filter_callables)) {
            // if there are more callables, recursively apply them on items of current array
            $modified_nested_array = array_map(static function (array $item) use ($filter_callables): array {
                return self::filterByFnRecursive($item, $filter_callables);
            }, $nested_array);
        } else {
            // otherwise keep the current array intact
            $modified_nested_array = $nested_array;
        }

        if (empty($filterer)) {
            // if callable is NULL, return array (at current level) unmodified
            // this is provided to allow skipping filtering at any level (by passing null callable)
            return $modified_nested_array;
        } else {
            // otherwise filter the items at current level
            return array_filter($modified_nested_array, $filterer, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Do checkout [this gist](https://gist.github.com/y2k-shubham/52f6f8e0e4ae566607ee6aec658a441c) for bigger [collection of array utility functions](https://gist.github.com/y2k-shubham/52f6f8e0e4ae566607ee6aec658a441c#file-arrayutils-php) along with [unit-tests](https://gist.github.com/y2k-shubham/52f6f8e0e4ae566607ee6aec658a441c#file-arrayutilstest-php)